# Moderator Tools and Deleting Questions section is inaccurate

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, privileges, vote-to-delete

On the [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) once you're 10K+ you can vote to delete closed questions with score of -3 or lower...

Which I find a bit inaccurate because a simple search `[vba] is:question closed:yes duplicate:no score:0` shows closed questions with positive score which **I can vote to delete**.

As far as I have noticed the score does not make any difference in terms of voting for deletion.

Is the quoted text

> Users with this reputation level can delete closed questions with a
>   score of -3 or lower

misleading/ inaccurate or/and outdated or have I missed something here?

Comment: It should say "immediately" at the end. If the score is higher than -3 you have to wait at least 2 days before you can vote to delete it, restriction dropped for trusted users.

Comment: even on the questions with score less than -3 you can't immediately delete it. I think this comes to play at 20K possibly but can't confirm as I am still just at 13k

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, that was just wrong. Fixed:

> #### Deleting questions
>
> Users with this reputation level can delete closed questions.
>
> ...
>
> You must wait for a question to be closed for **2** days before you can vote for deletion. This restriction is removed for trusted users when a post scores **-3** or lower. If you feel a post should be deleted despite having lots of votes or for being new, please **flag** it for community moderator attention.

Comment: where is my successful bug reporter badge ;P?

Comment: [No one here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze) has a bug badge yet - keep workin' on it...

Comment: will do chief!.